# How to fix Sequence contains no Elements Error on C#?

Tags: c#, rhino, grasshopper

I am currently working on a code for attractivity, where my concept is assigning cells to factor like Population, Green Spaces and Residential Spaces. I want to code an attractivity relation among these factors where, Population is attracted to green Spaces and Residential Spaces to Green Spaces. I have several C# components but some of them are not working due to this sequence contains no elements error. I cant seem to find the error within the code, I would appreciate if someone knows how to fix this. Thank you for your help!

```
//======================================================
// ------- compute the attractivity landscape ----------
//======================================================
// -- find the max distance value - usually the diagonal from first to last:
int nrLocations = Distances.BranchCount;
int nrDists = Distances.Branch(0).Count;
double maxDist = Distances.Branch(0)[nrDists - 1];

// -- the list store the attractivity values for population to green spaces and housing to green spaces
List<double> attractPop = new List<double>();
List<double> attractSpaces = new List<double>();
List<double> attractResid = new List<double>();
double maxPop = PopulDistrib.Max();
double maxSpaces = GreenSDistrib.Max();
double maxResid = ResiDistrib.Max();

for(int i = 0; i < nrLocations; i++)
{
  // -- reset lists in each loop:
  double curPopAttract = 0;
  double curSpacesAttract = 0;
  double curResidAttract = 0;
  for(int k = 0; k < nrDists; k++)
  {
    double curPop = PopulDistrib[k] / maxPop; // population of all cells
    double curSpaces = GreenSDistrib[k] / maxPop; // Green Spaces of all cells
    double curResid = ResiDistrib[k] / maxResid; // Residential Spaces of all cells

    // -- distances to all cells:
    // -- index i = from current cell // index k = to other cells
    // -- division by maxDist gives normalized values in the range [0; 1] for the distance
    double curDist = Distances.Branch(i)[k] / maxDist;

    // ** Remember: the distances are normalized! Therefore:
    // ** (1 - distance) :: makes close things more important than distant ones.
    // ** (Math.Pow(1-distance, 6); :: decrease the effect of the distance exponentially.
    // ** The perception of people concerning things in a certain distance can now be expressed by:
    double distPerceptPop = Math.Pow(1 - curDist, 7);
    //Print("distPercept: " + distPerceptPop.ToString());

    // -- in addition, we just cut the relevance of distant things completely:
    if (distPerceptPop < 0.4) distPerceptPop = 0;

    // -- corresponding "perception" of Green Spaces concerning things in a distance:
    double distPerceptSpaces = Math.Pow(1 - curDist, 2);

    // -- corresponding "perception" of Residential Space concerning things in a distance:
    double distPerceptResid = Math.Pow(1 - curDist, 4);

    // ----------- Attractivity Functions ----------------------
    // -- define the functions for the attractivity ------------
    // -- here we control, what is prefered by which land use --
    // -- linear attractivity function -> can become more complex functions!!!

    // -- people like to be close to Green Spaces:
    curPopAttract += ((distPerceptPop) * curSpaces );
    //double curAttract = ((distPerceptPop) * curPop );
    //curPopAttract += curAttract;
    //Print("attractivityPop: " + curPopAttract.ToString());

    // -- people DON'T like to be close to other people:
    //curPopAttract += 1- ((distPerceptPop) * curPop );

    // -- people DON'T like to be close to other people, + but to workplaces:
    //double weightImportWork = 0.3; // -- weighting factor to express the importancy to be close to workplaces in contrast to be away from other people
    //curPopAttract += 1- ((distPerceptPop) * curPop )     + weightImportWork * Math.Pow(1 - curDist, 2) * curWork;

    // -- Residential Spaces like to be close to Green Spaces
    curResidAttract += (distPerceptResid) * curSpaces;

    // *** EXPERIMENT WITH THE ATTRACTIVITY FUNCTIONS ABOVE !!! **********************************
    // *** You may also add additional relations similar to the other system dynamics examples ***
  }
  // -- collect the current values in the attractivity values lists:
  attractPop.Add(curPopAttract);
  attractSpaces.Add(curSpacesAttract);
  attractResid.Add(curResidAttract);
}

//=======================================================
// -- normalize the attractivity values for both lists --
double minPopAtt = attractPop.Min();
double maxPopAtt = attractPop.Max();
double minSpacesAtt = attractSpaces.Min();
double maxSpacesAtt = attractSpaces.Max();
double minResidAtt = attractResid.Min();
double maxResidAtt = attractResid.Max();

// -- formula for normalization to the range [0; 1]:
// -- normalized valueOfList = (valueOfList - minValueOfList) * 1 / maxValueOfList
for(int i = 0; i < attractPop.Count; i++)
{
  attractPop[i] = (attractPop[i] - minPopAtt) * (1 / maxPopAtt);
  attractSpaces[i] = (attractSpaces[i] - minSpacesAtt) * (1 / maxSpacesAtt);
  attractResid[i] = (attractResid[i] - minResidAtt) * (1 / maxResidAtt);
}

//=======================================================
// -- return the lists:
AttractPop = attractPop;
AttractSpaces = attractSpaces;
AttractResid = attractResid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.Max()` or `.Min()` on an empty collection.

Check for empty collections, e.g. using `if (!collection.Any()) ...`, and then either abort (if that is an input error), or adjust the algorithm to account for it.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply , by adjusting the algorithm do you mean this kind of formulas?   // -- in addition, we just cut the relevance of distant things completely:
        if (distPerceptPop < 0.4) distPerceptPop = 0;

Comment: I have no idea what to do with your algorithms, I assume you know what they do. You have to decide for yourself if they can be executed at all in case of empty collections, and if so, how they should behave or what default value they will use. Perhaps aborting is the most suitable, because you are dividing by the Max-values, and you can't divide by 0.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says, you are calling `Min()` and `Max()` on an empty collection.

A work around would be:

```
double minPopAtt = attractPop.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
```

-1 will be your default value in case your collection is empty.

Comment: Thanks Haitam for your reply! I tried what you said on the last part on this part of my code : //=======================================================
    // -- normalize the attractivity values for both lists --
    double minPopAtt = attractPop.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
    double maxPopAtt = attractPop.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Max();
  But it still doesnt work, I am not so experienced with C#

Comment: You have to modify the lines of all the Max()s and Min()s you use, not only the first one (in your case its 6 lines).